# interprocess and time based process controlling with select() and pipes in c language

Tags: c, select, pipe, fork, ipc

Iam currently working on a program where I log OBD-data from my car. Currently Iam stucking on the problem to record these data every 500ms. I want to use the select() function for that because I got three child processes:

- videoLog
- GPSLog
- OBDLog

and my parent process: **main**

I want that the **GPSLog and OBDLog** record data every 500ms and the **videoLog** should run the whole time.
Iam currently stucking on how to architect the software, that it is good to code.

How can I controll my **GPSLog and PBDLog** that they **record at the same time (every 500ms)** and log the data to a mySQL DB? The rest of the time, no of the two processes should do anything.

I would like to get a scheme or a example Code of that by you guys. Using select() and pipe().
I can't really make a start here.

Best wishes,

FloKl

Comment: Do you need a high precision timer? Then `select` isn't it, and unless you also want to poll descriptors I suggest you do some searching regarding timers for your operating system (Linux?). You will get plenty of hits and examples.

Comment: everything with under ~50ms gap is okay. I think a high precision timer is not necessary here. And yes, Iam operating on Linux (rasbian)

Comment: on linux, suggest using the function: `setitimer()`

Comment: Thank your for your replay. Could you give me a little example how to structure the code for two running child process, that they start every 500ms to gather data? Thank you!